# Chainlink Kaleido Contract compilation

Tags: solidity, chainlink, kaleido

I am trying to re-compile the ChainlinkEthPrice contract found in the Kaleido Sample Gallery here: https://kaleido-io.github.io/kaleido-samples-gallery/#/kaleido-samples-gallery/chainlink.

Codes as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./Chainlinked.sol";

contract ChainlinkEthPrice is Chainlinked {

    struct EthPriceAtBlock
    {
        uint    blockNumber;
        uint    blockTimestamp;
        bytes32 requestId;
        uint256 reportedPrice;
    }

    EthPriceAtBlock[] public ethPrices;
    bytes32 jobId;

    constructor(bytes32 _jobId, address linkTokenAddr, address oracleAddr)
        public
    {
        jobId = _jobId;
        setLinkToken(linkTokenAddr);
        setOracle(oracleAddr);
    }

    function requestEthereumPrice(string _currency)
        public returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        ChainlinkLib.Run memory run = newRun(jobId, this, "fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32,uint256)");
        run.add("url", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,JPY");
        run.add("path", _currency);
        run.addInt("times", 100);
        requestId = chainlinkRequest(run, LINK(0));
    }

    function fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _reportedPrice)
        public checkChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        ethPrices.push(EthPriceAtBlock({
            blockNumber: block.number,
            blockTimestamp: block.timestamp,
            requestId: _requestId,
            reportedPrice: _reportedPrice
        }));
       emit RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(_requestId, _reportedPrice, block.number, block.timestamp);
    }

    event RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        uint256 indexed reportedPrice,
        uint256 blockNumber,
        uint256 blockTimestamp
    );

    function getDataCount()
        public view returns (uint length)
    {
        return ethPrices.length;
    }

    function getData(uint idx)
        public view returns (uint blockNumber, uint256 reportedPrice)
    {
        return (ethPrices[idx].blockNumber, ethPrices[idx].reportedPrice);
    }
}
```

Received the following errors:

```
browser/chainlink.sol:27:59: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32,uint256)" to bytes4 requested.
    ChainlinkLib.Run memory run = newRun(jobId, this, "fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32,uint256)");
                                                      ^-------------------------------------^

browser/chainlink.sol:31:43: TypeError: Type is not callable
    requestId = chainlinkRequest(run, LINK(0));
                                      ^-----^

browser/chainlink.sol:31:43: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from tuple() to uint256 requested.
    requestId = chainlinkRequest(run, LINK(0));
                                      ^-----^
```

Wondering if anyone can help with this. Thank you!

Comment: Tip: If there is no specific reason to use exactly this to fetch the ETH price, I would recommend using Oraclize.it - it is well documented and has a plugin in Remix for testing.

Comment: There is an important why I didn't use Oraclize. I am doing this on Kaleido.io, a private blockchain platform which uses chainlink.

Comment: I commented on your answer too: Oraclize also works on eth-compliant private blockchains, via the ethereum-bridge (https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge). So you can port over all your existing, Oraclize-using smart-contract architecture no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the folks who suggested Oraclize - which is what I have been using for my projects on the public blockchain. I used Chainlink here because it works with Kaleido.io, a private blockchain platform that I use for my project.

Anyway, Thomas Hodges from ChainLink has helped me with this. These were the changes he made:

From:

```
ChainlinkLib.Run memory run = newRun(jobId, this,"fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32,uint256)");
```

To:

```
ChainlinkLib.Run memory run = newRun(jobId, this, this.fulfillEthereumPrice.selector);
```

And from:

```
requestId = chainlinkRequest(run, LINK(0));
```

To:

```
requestId = chainlinkRequest(run, 0);
```

Now it works just the way it should.

Comment: Good work getting it up and running. If you're already familiar with Oraclize, you'll be thrilled to know that Oraclize already works with any eth-compliant private block-chains, via the ethereum-bridge (https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge) So you can port over all your existing smart-contracts with no issue!

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I can't help specifically with those errors, I can help with creating a smart-contract that gets the current price of ETH in USD using Oraclize per the comment on your question:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract EthPriceTicker is usingOraclize {

    string public ethPriceUSD;

    event LogEthPrice(string priceUSD);

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string memory result, bytes memory proof) public {
        require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
        ethPriceUSD = result;
        emit LogEthPrice(result);
    }

    function getEthPriceInUSD() public payable {
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,JPY).USD");
    }
}
```

#### Instructions:

- Copy and paste the above into [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) (a solidity IDE)
- Ensure your have a solc compiler version greater than `0.5` selected.
- Compile the contract
- Load the Oraclize plugin from the `settings` tab at the top right hand side
- Switch to the `run` tab and click on `deploy`
- Once deployed, expand the tab that appeared below to see the functions in the contract. Then click on `getEthPrice`& watch the Oraclize plugin do its thing.